# Is there an "alt-left" since there is the word "alt-right" in English?

Tags: word-request

The word "alt-right" is everywhere to see on TV and social media.

Does "alt-left" also exist in English language? Why is "alt-right" widely used while "alt-left" seldom used or seen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about political terminology, and is not about learning English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "alt-right" has been in the news because of the noise they made during the elections in the US.

> alt-right

is short for "alternative-right" and is a far-right political movement.

The [alt-left](https://altleft.com) does exist, but it may not be what you expect it to be.

Since "alt-" is being used as a shortened form of "alternative", practically *anything* that could be called "alternative" might use "alt-".

As an aside, "alt-" also has the meaning in computer science of holding down the "alt" key while pressing a secondary key creating a two-keystroke command, e.g. alt-A.